# CSS Gradient Text with Opacity and Gradient Text Stroke / Outline

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients, css-gradients

Although I've found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215721/gradient-colour-with-linear-gradient-border-in-text-using-css-not-working), none explicitly match my goal.

I'm trying to display text with a gradient colour, with low opacity (so you can see the background through it), but also with a (matching) solid gradient border (i.e. text-stroke). I've discovered that answers to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215721/gradient-colour-with-linear-gradient-border-in-text-using-css-not-working) develop a workaround by creating a `::before` underlay state that replicates a (gradient) border effect, but changing the opacity on the text's natural state just displays the colour of the `::before` underlay text *instead of* the background colour (the desired result).

What I'm wondering is, is there any workaround to *effectively* create a solid gradient text-stroke with (internal) gradient text that has an opacity lower than 1?

Using the aforementioned other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215721/gradient-colour-with-linear-gradient-border-in-text-using-css-not-working), I've developed the following code over a period of hours but can't quite figure out how it can be done. You'll notice in my code that I've used different `rgba` values - this was simply done to view the result more easily and see if I acheived my intended goal of making the (internal) text have opacity (to enable the background to be seen), as opposed to using identical colours. The more opacity I apply, the more you can see the gradient colours of the *workaround/makeshift* text-stroke.

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: arial;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7),
      rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.7),
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7));
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-180deg, #3399ff, #82ed89, #3399ff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Text">Text</h1>
```

Comment: for the question you linked, did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56234003/8620333? with SVG you can easily do it

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes - similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48795143/css-text-with-gradient-and-gradient-outline) I wanted to avoid the use of SVG (or any images) and see if there's a way to do it entirely with CSS, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the only way i can think about using CSS and without SVG is to rely on `element()` combined with `mask` but still the support is too low:

Here is an example that will only work in Firefox. The trick is to create a text with only stroke and transparent color as a reference that will be used inside a mask of the same text where we have the same stroke to keep only the stroke visible and get the needed effect. Yes, it's a bit crazy as idea but it works.

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: arial;
  color:#fff;
}
#ref {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px red;
  color:transparent;
  display:inline-block;
}
h1.grad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4),
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5));
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  margin: 10px;
}
h1.grad::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

h1.grad::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #3399ff, #82ed89, #3399ff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-mask:element(#ref);
          mask:-moz-element(#ref);
          mask:element(#ref);
}

body {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/107/1000/1000) center/cover;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Some Text" class="grad"></h1>


<div style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
<h1 id="ref">Some Text</h1>
</div>
```

Below how it should look:

[image]

Another idea is to consider `background-attachment:fixed` and use the same background twice. This should work everywhere but you background will be fixed:

```css
body {
  background: #000000;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: arial;
  color:#fff;
}

h1.grad {
  background: linear-gradient(to left,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3),
      rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.4),
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)),
      url(https://picsum.photos/id/110/1000/1200) center/cover fixed;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
  margin: 10px;
}
h1.grad::after {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

h1.grad::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #3399ff, #82ed89, #3399ff);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 5px transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

body {
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/110/1000/1200) center/cover fixed;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="Some Text" class="grad"></h1>
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent - the final version worked a treat (best one for differing browsers), but I will note that it can only be used with non-transparent bitmap images. Hopefully they'll update CSS with a gradient text-stroke feature - would be a useful feature for a variety of projects, particularly those with transparent backgrounds or backgrounds set on the user's device. Thanks for your help with this!